# How to retrieve nested data in firebase -realtime database (using javascript) HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

We are trying to retrieve data from a nested parent child relationship from realtime database from firebase using javascript (Html). Below is the code  we are using and output, but the section of where there is nested data we are getting [object, Object] and undefined. We get the desired output on the console but not on the webpage.

```
    const db = getDatabase();
    
    var tablebody = document.getElementById('assQuestions');

    var asspool = [];


    function addassquesvalues(quescat,quesid,queslaws,lawname,statements,question){

        let trow=document.createElement('tr');
        let td1=document.createElement('td');
        let td2=document.createElement('td');
        let td3=document.createElement('td');
        let td4=document.createElement('td');
        let td5=document.createElement('td');
        let td6=document.createElement('td');

        asspool.push(quescat,question,queslaws);
        td1.innerHTML = quescat;
        td2.innerHTML = quesid;
        td3.innerHTML = queslaws;
        td4.innerHTML = lawname;
        td5.innerHTML = statements;
        td6.innerHTML = question;

        trow.appendChild(td1);
        trow.appendChild(td2);
        trow.appendChild(td3);
        trow.appendChild(td4);
        trow.appendChild(td5);
        trow.appendChild(td6);
        tablebody.appendChild(trow);

        console.log(queslaws)
    }


    function addassquesvaluestotable(questions){
        tablebody.innerHTML="";
        questions.forEach(element=>{
            addassquesvalues(element.quescat, element.quesid, element.queslaws, element.lawname, element.statements, element.question);
        })

    }

    
    function getdatarealtime(){
        const dbref=ref(db,"AssessmentQues");
        onValue(dbref,(snapshot)=>{
            var allassques = [];
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                allassques.push(childSnapshot.val());
            });
            addassquesvaluestotable(allassques);
        })
    }

    window.onload = getdatarealtime;
```

[Output in form of a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmhVk.png)

Comment: You see this because you either try to print a value that is not defined or an Object. I would suggest you start [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.